# Android Wear project with multiple flavour dimensions

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, wear-os, android-productflavors

## The problem

We encountered an issue with a project that has multiple (2) product flavour dimensions and a wear module. On building a release we get no compile errors and the phone app works but the wear app is never synced to watch.

## Code example

Phone app module `build.gradle` contains (example and only an extract)

```
flavorDimensions 'brand', 'type'

productFlavors {
    nikon {
        dimension 'brand'
    }
    canon {
        dimension 'brand'
    }
    compact {
        dimension 'type'
    }
    slr {
        dimension 'type'
    }
}

dependencies {
    wearApp project(':wear')
}
```

Wear app module `build.gradle` contains the same dimension config

```
publishNonDefault true

flavorDimensions 'brand', 'type'

productFlavors {
    nikon {
        dimension 'brand'
    }
    canon {
        dimension 'brand'
    }
    compact {
        dimension 'type'
    }
    slr {
        dimension 'type'
    }
}

dependencies {

}
```

## What we did

We checked if the wear app is in the apk by installing on phone and triggering the wear apps sync option from the official android wear app. In the logging you then get an overview of `packageId`s that get synced to watch:

```
I/WearablePkgInstaller: Setting DataItem to install wearable apps for your.package.id.here
```

We also tried to specify the flavours in the dependencies redirecting to a specific configuration.

```
nikonCompactWearApp compile(path:':wear', configuration:'nikonCompactRelease')
```

However adding both flavour dimensions breaks the build right away. Having a single flavour dimension does work and has the wear app published properly but we really want the multiple dimensions.

```
nikonWearApp compile(path:':wear', configuration:'nikonCompactRelease')
```

### The obvious

Just to be clear, the wear app worked before we switched to multiple dimensions. We also checked the obvious wear apk packaging options like:

- have same applicationId for both phone and wear app
- have all permission from wear app also on phone app
- building a release since debug never includes the wear app
- publishNonDefault true is set in the wear module

Comment: this should be reported as a bug or a feature enchancement. I had the same issue and had to result to only a single flavor in build.gradle wearable.